# Sql query to select the most recent in one to many relationship two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a one to many relationship table such as customer to activities table as shown below
**Customer table**

```
   Id  Name
   1   Customer 1
   2   Customer 2
```

**Customer activities**

```
Id  customer_id activity created

1      1       Login    2017-01-01 10:52:32
2      1       Logout   2017-01-01 11:75:32
3      2       Post     2017-01-02 10:11:10
4      2       LogOut   2017-01-02 09:11:10
```

Let assume I have this repeated to thousand both customer table and customer activities.
How can I write a single sql (using Mysql) to show the most recent record per each of the customer using created date such as having the result of activities below

```
Id  customer_id activity created

2      1       Logout   2017-01-01 11:75:32
3      2       Post     2017-01-02 10:11:10
```

example should be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_activities 
WHERE created IN 
(
    SELECT MAX(created)
    FROM customer_activities 
    GROUP BY customer_id
);
```

But the above did not return the required result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the subquery with aggregate and `join`

```
select * 
from customer_activities  c
join (
   select customer_id, max(created) max_created
   from customer_activities 
   group by customer_id
) t on c.customer_id = t.customer_id and
       c.created = t.max_created
```

or `in` construct

```
select * 
from customer_activities  c
where (customer_id, created) in (
   select customer_id, max(created) max_created
   from customer_activities 
   group by customer_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will prefer that of 'in construct' as is very precises and clean